# Flexslider using a slider with carousel, but TWO in the same page, it fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, flexslider

Im using flexslider using a slider with a carousel below as here:

http://flexslider.woothemes.com/thumbnail-slider.html

That works fine, BUT im using BootStrap tabs like here:

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

Now im having a problem, because when im using more than one slider with carousel NOT WORKS :(

this is my FlexSlider javascript file:

```js
    // The slider being synced must be initialized first
    $('#carousel').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        controlNav: false,
        animationLoop: true,
        slideshow: false,
        itemWidth: 150,
        itemMargin: 5,
        asNavFor: '#slider'

    });


    $('#slider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        controlNav: false,
        animationLoop: true,
        slideshow: true,
        sync: "#carousel",
        slideshowSpeed: 1500
    });
```

I`ve tried to put a "#carousel2" and "#slider2" to each new slider and add JS to my file BUT it not works, also i found that "#carousel" has css style so i need to hold this id in each new slide.

=(